# How segue from a button in a custom tableviewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am building an app for a local football club. On on screen I want to show all players in a sort of a grid. When you click on a players photo inside the grid, you get more information about that player.
I am working with a customTableViewCell. This tableView cell contains 6 buttons. Behind each button you find some Player information. I am setting the players images in the grid like this. First of all I have a method in my custumTableViewCell.

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forPosition:(NSUInteger)position{
    if(position == 1){
        [_btnPlayer1 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if(position == 2){
        [_btnPlayer2 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if(position == 3){
        [_btnPlayer3 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if(position == 4){
        [_btnPlayer4 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if(position == 5){
        [_btnPlayer5 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if(position == 6){
        [_btnPlayer6 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

And in my CellForRowAtIndexPath I am doing the following.

```
 NSInteger frcRow = indexPath.row * IMAGES_PER_ROW; // row in fetched results controller

    for (int col = 1; col <= IMAGES_PER_ROW; col++) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:frcRow inSection:0];
        Team *team = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
        NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:team.image]];
        UIImage *image;
        if (imgData == nil) {
            // default image
            image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"keeperNil.jpg"];
        } else {
            image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        }
        [cell setImage:image forPosition:col];
        frcRow ++;
    }
    return cell;
```

But now I want to determine which button is pressed and then segue to a detailViewController which shows the correct information. Anybody got an idea how I can do that?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong way to achieve what you want to do.  Find a photo viewer such as Three20 (take Three20 as an example, it is old with no ARC and there are better alternatives on Git) and segue to a new view based on the selection of each player photo.

If you really wanted to (although it seems like poor design IMO) you could hook up 6 buttons and tag them, then choose a player based on the button tag selected, but this really doesn't seem like the best use of UITableView